# How to open jquery accordion panel with a link in a different accordion panel

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am stuck on getting accordion panels to open from links in other accordion panels. For example, I have 5 accordion panels. How can I put a link in panel 1 to  open panel 4?

Comment: Include code to remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as opening the panels from any other place outside your accordion.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nb9T/16/

```
$('#section1').click(function(){
     $('#accordion').accordion('option','active',0); 
});
```

would be the way if you use Jquery UI for example.